# How to set Analytic Units (AUs) to U-SQL Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, u-sql

How to set Analytic Units (AUs) in a U-SQL Activity in Azure Data Factory v2.
Simple as that.  I've crawled documentation and can't manage to find out what the parameter is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your U-SQL activity in ADF you have script advanced settings ---> Degree of parallelism, you can define how many AUs you want. Be aware that 32 is the max.

[image]